# WebEngineView QML type need flash player to install

Tags: qt, flash, qtwebengine

I'm using WebEngine Qt Quick Minimal Example to build a simple program to load a page contains some texts and an video which is shown using Adobe Flash Player. 
I can see the video on my Google Chrome but when i try to load the page in the mentioned example, following error appear instead of Adobe Flash Player:

> This video requires Adobe Flash Player 10.2

I have downloaded Adobe Flash Player plugin for every browser but no change is occurred!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using flash player in WebEngine needs three step:

1. Installing `Pepper Flash Player Plugin`
2. Load plugin to QT
3. Enabling this feature in WebEngineView

**STEP 1:**

Download `Pepper Flash Player Plugin` from anywhere you want (Recommend you to download it from Adobe website). Pepper plugin is another version of Flash Player plugin made to be used in Chromium-based browser, e.g WebEngine. Install it like other version of this plugin.

**STEP 2:**

[Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#pepper-flash-player-plugin-support) says that:

> The Pepper Flash player plugin can be loaded automatically if it is installed in one of the following locations, depending on the platform ...

So you need no action to done this step, because install program copies necessary files.

**STEP 3:**

Change `QtWebEngine` version to 1.3 in your `.qml` file:

```
import QtWebEngine 1.3
```

Add following line under `WebEngineView` in your `.qml` file:

```
settings.pluginsEnabled : true
```

Your `.qml` file should be like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.3

Window {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "http://127.0.0.1"
        settings.pluginsEnabled : true
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `settings.pluginsEnabled : true` did a thing for me. I tried to enable plugins from main.cpp upon initialization of the app, this didn't work.